# Android error log after app crash

Tags: android

I received **>>>[THIS](http://pastebin.com/HFZKi4bJ)<<<** error log from a client. I replaced the app name with: APP_NAME. **Can you help me determine if it was my app's fault?** It seems to me that something went wrong outside my app and caused the error in a service:

> 06-30 15:54:51.059 W/ActivityManager(  427): Scheduling restart of
>   crashed service
>   com..android/.services.periodic.GpsLoggerService

But I'm not sure if it was the real cause of the error message. **Was it?**

The log was taken and sent by an **external tool**. **Log collector**. So it's not just a log from my app, but from whole system.

Comment: Can you add the source code which correspond to the error, please

Comment: @Guillaume unfortunately I can't. The source code is company's property, not mine. :( Currently I'm only concerned if it was my app that failed or something else. If it turns out it's my app I'll dig into code. PS note that there is the whole log on pastebin, not only this one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the pastebin, I can definitely say for certain is seems your app has b0rk3d up. Look at lines 457-465 which shows the

java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
06-30 15:54:51.049 D/Process (11724): java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
06-30 15:54:51.049 D/Process (11724): dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Something happened in the thread there, perhaps, mishandling the thread management, also at line 804 your broadcast receiver, perhaps received some intent, which is causing your app to crash as a whole.

I know its not much help but hope it helps you in the right direction.

Comment: Hmm.. I should've mentioned it in the question. The log was taken and sent by an external tool. Log collector. So it's not just a log from my app, but from whole system. I noticed these lines but they didn't seem to me to be related to my app. Though I may be wrong...

Comment: process 11724 is your offending app that is crashing :)

Comment: Good point. Some circumstances would be helpful. Was my app's process force killed by system? (I mean the line 458 "killProcess, pid=11724")

Comment: Look, closely at the 'uncaught exception in the thread' some threading error so yes, dalvikvm killed your process, if an exception occurs that's not handled, dalvikvm steps in and kills it.

Comment: I guess the best thing I can do now is put Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler in every activity and service, display some more info in there and wait for another crash. Am I right?

Comment: Basically yes, only for the temporary duration, that will help you nail down the source of the problem and hopefully point you to the line directly where the source of the problem is.  Did you not receive exactly the steps necessary to reproduce it? If not that is bad! You should get back to the person or persons responsible for submitting the logcat to your attention, and pester them for your own sanity's sake. :)